# Typo3 - Add class to disabled page in typoscript hmenu

Tags: menu, typo3, typoscript

I have different pages disabled from the Typo3 backend, in the main menu of the website, but still remain visible in the frontend thanks to **includeNotInMenu = 1**.
What I want to do is to **give these disabled pages a class="disabled" which I can use to add pointer-events: none** to it. Is that possible? I admit that typoscript syntax is not easily understandable at all.

Comment: so where should this class be added? to the body tag or in the menu and how do you currently render the menu?

Comment: The class should be added to the menu link or li. The menu is constructed this way:
lib.menu = HMENU
lib.menu {

  special = directory
  special.value = 51
  includeNotInMenu = 1

  1 = TMENU
  1.expAll = 1

  1.NO = 1
  1.NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>

  1.ACT = 1
  1.ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="current-page">|</li>

  1.wrap = <nav><ul>|</ul></nav>
}

Comment: `allWrap` is of type "wrap /stdWrap". So you can override `1.NO.allWrap` for the special case of "not-in-menu"-pages. 
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#override
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html
('disabled' would more be the property 'hidden', which will not show the page in the menu at all)